# civicrm " Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. " joomla

Tags: civievent, joomla, civicrm-contact, civicrm-event

Facing an issue in civicrm contact for a  particular contact. As in events that contact has near about 60 events which he/she participated in but when i view that contact it shows the count of events correctly but on click its show " Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.see image [image]

Dec 23 06:56:09  [debug] $backTrace = #0 /home/nihcmlive/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(385): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
=>1 /home/nihcmlive/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1195): CRM_Core_Error::fatal()
=>2 /home/nihcmlive/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/BAO/Event.php(1029): CRM_Core_DAO::getFieldValue("CRM_Event_DAO_Event", NULL, "is_monetary")
=>3 /home/nihcmlive/public_html/media/civicrm/custom2/extensions/com.servnettech.participantlistemaildisplay/CRM/Event/Selector/Search.php(402): CRM_Event_BAO_Event::isMonetary(NULL)
=>4 /home/nihcmlive/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Selector/Controller.php(420): CRM_Event_Selector_Search->getRows(4, 0, 50, Object(CRM_Utils_Sort), 1, NULL)
=>5 /home/nihcmlive/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Selector/Controller.php(341): CRM_Core_Selector_Controller->getRows(Object(CRM_Core_Selector_Controller))
=>6 /home/nihcmlive/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Search.php(373): CRM_Core_Selector_Controller->run()
=>7 /home/nihcmlive/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Search.php(409): CRM_Event_Form_Search->submit((Array:0))
=>8 /home/nihcmlive/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Search.php(109): CRM_Event_Form_Search->postProcess()
=>9 /home/nihcmlive/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(590): CRM_Event_Form_Search->preProcess()
=>10 /home/nihcmlive/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(92): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()
=>11 /home/nihcmlive/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Event_Form_Search), "display")
=>12 /home/nihcmlive/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Event_Form_Search), "display")
=>13 /home/nihcmlive/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("display")
=>14 /home/nihcmlive/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Page/Tab.php(54): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
=>15 /home/nihcmlive/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Page/Tab.php(190): CRM_Event_Page_Tab->browse()
=>16 /home/nihcmlive/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(290): CRM_Event_Page_Tab->run((Array:4), NULL)
=>17 /home/nihcmlive/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:12))
=>18 /home/nihcmlive/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4))
=>19 /home/nihcmlive/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(121): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
=>20 /home/nihcmlive/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(40): civicrm_invoke()
=>21 /home/nihcmlive/public_html/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php(402): require_once("/home/nihcmlive/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")
=>22 /home/nihcmlive/public_html/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php(377): Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::executeComponent("/home/nihcmlive/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")
=>23 /home/nihcmlive/public_html/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php(101): Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm")
=>24 /home/nihcmlive/public_html/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php(159): Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->dispatch()
=>25 /home/nihcmlive/public_html/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php(196): Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->doExecute()
=>26 /home/nihcmlive/public_html/administrator/index.php(51): Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()
=>27 {main}
"

Comment: check you check civicrm logs for more detailed information about the error? and paste it here?

Comment: Thanks @jitendra. yes i have check the error log also.

Answer (score 2):

From the backtrace, it looks like the error is due to the participantlistemaildisplay (https://github.com/voiply/com.servnettech.participantlistemaildisplay) extension enabled on your site.

To fix -

- Try disabling this ext from `civicrm/admin/extensions?reset=1`.
- Create an issue on the extension repo - https://github.com/voiply/com.servnettech.participantlistemaildisplay/issues with steps to replicate the problem. Note that this ext isn't updated in last 3 years.

Comment: you may need to clear caches too